# How can I start a fire by rubbing two sticks together?

Tags: survival, fire-starting

When trying to start a fire by rubbing two sticks together, what does one need to consider? I am assuming I can't just grab any two sticks and start rubbing...

- Should they be dead or green?
- Hard wood or soft wood?
- Is spinning or scraping more efficient?

Comment: Best way, if using the traditional method, will be the Bow-Drill method. I have done this method many times and youtube has a lot of good video how-tos. Once you get the basic set up down, using the proper wood for both the dill and board you will have a new skill and the confidence of knowing you don't need matches, lighter, or flint. Only tip I can give is... Don't use dead/rotting wood. You may want to let your bow & drill cure for a bit if take from fresh live trees. But There is enough wood around to be able to pick up and start practicing right away. Just have patience. Happy Trails

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are many, many ways to make a fire. Some require more skill, while others depend on carefully prepared equipment.

[image]
The closest thing to "rubbing two sticks together" is the **hand-drill**. You will need a fireboard (a small cedar board is good) and a thin, straight stick. A knife is good, too. This takes a lot of practice. Hand callouses help. YouTube has many videos: [Fire Plow (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hand+drill+fire).

[image]
Even further on the skill end of the scale is the **fire plow**. Basically you push a stick along a groove in a board. I've heard that native people of the Pacific Northwest would walk up to a cedar tree, cut groove in the side of the tree, and plow up a coal right there. Again, see YouTube: [Fire Plow (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=fire%20plow).

**Successful friction fires requires both good equipment and good technique.** If you are just starting out, and you won't know if your failures are caused by equipment or technique. This can make learning very difficult. One fix is to buy a good set from an expert. Learn to make fires with it, then make your own kit.

Making any fire requires **multiple skills**, which you apply in a sequence. A friction method will produce a tiny coal. Once you've mastered that, you still need to be able to make the coal in to a flame (with tinder). Once your tinder is going, you need to light the kindling. Usually you'll add progressively larger fuel to grow the fire for your purposes. Then you need to know [how to put the fire out safely](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-to-be-absolutely-sure-my-fire-is-safely-extinguished).

Each of these stages is its own set of skills to learn. Each is contextual (type of wood available, season, weather, etc.).

**Wet weather** is especially challenging, so start learning when it's not raining. However, watch out for your dry season, when runaway fires are particularly risky. Check with your fire department for **burn bans**.

There is no mastery of fire-making. Sometimes, when you're sure that you're doing everything right, you still can't get a good fire going. Consider it a **spiritual practice**.

Answer (score 20):

I suggest using a bow drill. It's a little tricky to start, but once you get the hang of it you can get pretty good at it.

For wood selections, you generally want to stick with the following:

1. Obviously Dry.
2. You should be able to press into the wood. If you can't at all then it's too hard.
3. However, if you can make a fingertip-sized depression then it's too soft.
4. Make sure there isn't any sap in the wood.

Types of wood to look for are sycamore, willow, and dogwood.

Here's a good site with step-by-step instructions for constructing a bow drill set.

[natureskills.com](http://www.natureskills.com/survival/creating-a-bow-drill/)

**EDIT**
A tip I learned from a buddy: put sap on the end of the spindle that is not doing the drilling. That way it doesn't make a fire in your hand piece.

Comment: An alternative to putting sap on the spindle is to pack a waxy leaf (e.g. holly) into the hole on the bearing block.

Answer (score 6):

I have successfully made friction fires before, and it is possible. That said, it is not easy. I would reccomend leaning the bow drill. Use basswood, western red/eastern white cedars, poplar or cottonwood, among others. It is easier than other methods, but still requires a lot of practice. When I was learning the hand drill, I practiced EVERY DAY before I got my first ember. Practice often!

Answer (score -9):

You can't. Bring a lighter and matches :)

I've seen so-called fire starting "experts" who say they can start a fire with sticks using a spindle or bow, but it almost never works in real life. They usually have a board with special notches or holes (which you won't find in the woods) and special wood. If you're in a survival situation where you need to make fire, these methods are usually too complicated, require too many specific things you won't find in nature, and very time consuming to assemble and use.

Just pack a few lighters and keep them on you at all times.

Comment: Or just use some magnesium sticks instead of wood ;-)

Comment: Hm, that's strange.  I suppose all the times I have seen people do it in a real life situation, I must have been hallucinating.  Of course you need to know what you are doing, but frankly, if you cannot chop a straight piece of wood and cut a notch in it with a knife, what in the ... are you doing in wilderness?

Comment: I am down-voting this answer for the following reasons: --The original question did not say this was an emergency survival situation, but only asked for techniques. --Though perhaps difficult, it is possible, so "You can't" is just wrong. --"Bring a lighter" is not very constructive, nor germane to the question.

Comment: I admit my answer is a bit cheeky. But if a friend came to me asking how to start a fire by rubbing two sticks together, this is what I'd tell them. It's one of those "woah, I can't believe he did that!" novelty camping tricks, not something that should actually be relied on.

Comment: I do not agree with that.  I know number of people who can do it reliably, in bad weather, rain, snow, etc.  If you know what you are doing, you can rely on it just as much as you can rely on matches or lighters. there are obviously different camping styles, some people like to bring all sorts of modern tools and equipment, others prefer to "stay closer to nature", and for those, making fire in a way that people used for 100's of years may be of great value.

Comment: If you need it demonstrated, see http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=friction%20fire

Comment: I taught my two eldest kids to do it, first just using hands,then a bow. It is hard work, and I'd expect them to always have a flint, but it is good to know you can do it in an emergency.

Comment: Or perhaps press the emergency beacon that everyone has attached to their rumps and wait for help. Or perhaps call mommy and daddy to come get you out of this pickle. I'm sorry but from what I've seen on this board, I can tell most of you haven't spent enough time in the wilderness with only a pocket knife and your imagination on how to create something from nothing. It seems to me that if it isn't "store bought" then it's not the correct way of doing it (Climbing excluded).

Comment: Continuation.... For those that know bush-crafting, how to read signs, find water, watch the animal and plants for signs of danger. Props to you, you are the few who know what Nature really is and how much it needs to be protected.

Comment: I voted this up again because expecting to make a fire without equipment pre-designed to do so is borderline absurd for most people. I carry a tin of matches.